# Oracle JDK 11 error occuring every time, I install anything in terminal

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

Below is the Error message I get every time I install anything in the terminal . Its kinda stuck there for a while.

I tried no. of solutions from StackOverflow but nothing worked.

Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Doesn't show up again.

Comment: This seems to be answered on the Ubuntu Forum --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/126372/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-7u3-linux-x64-tar-gz-error-when-trying-to-install-orac

Answer (score 47):

Remove the package `oracle-java11-installer-local`. You can do this in following way:

```
sudo apt remove oracle-java11-installer-local
```

Comment: `java -version
java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
` means my Java is ok?

Comment: actually, something weird is happening, please check my question: 
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185084/ubuntu-oracle-jdk-issues-but-version-looks-okay

Comment: you don't have to remove the oracle-java11-installer-local, only if you switch to a newer version of Java (ex: 12)

Answer (score 15):

found this solution:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java11-installer-local.postinst
```

at [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sha256sum-mismatch-jdk-11-0-5_linux-x64_bin-tar-gz-4175664982/) site.

Comment: Can confirm this fixed it for me. Likely a result of trying to install the .deb file before the .tar.gz one.

Comment: I think it works ..the error has gone :) thanks

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and this was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, this one worked on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 7):

You need to download the folder of the Oracle JDK 11 on here https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html
After download the tar.gz file. Move to your folder location then copy the file by using this command

```
sudo cp jdk-11.0.6_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
```

don't forget to check your file name! After that repeat again by typing

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java11-installer-local
```

and you can check your java version after that by typing

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hello**,

I've had **the same issue**.

When you try to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it will automatically try to update the Java if a newer version is available. In my case let's say from **11.0.4** -> **11.0.5**.

If you add the JDK from Oracle (after download) to `/var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/` it **should work**.

You don't have to uninstall it...(I mean the oracle-jdk11-installer-local, it works just fine).

Please let me know if you still have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution was to download jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz and copied it to /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local.

In console shell, type:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: How is this answer substantially different from that given by Rareș Flueraș?

Answer (score 1):

After a long search: this solved it for me.
The checksum made the issues for me. Try:

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java11-installer-local.postinst -f

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the issue by doing this:

1. modify `/var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java11-installer-local.postinst`
2. Change the checkSum. take from oracle website [check sum for 11.0.15.1](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/11-0-15-1-checksum.html)

3. change the version in 2 places
4. save and update apt
5. then `sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer-local`

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to the directory var/cache and doing "sudo rmdir oracle-jdk11-installer-local/" worked for me.

```
sudo rmdir oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
```